# Converting numpy code to pytorch removing for loop

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, vision

My understanding is, using for loops in python is going to make our code slower. Hence, they should be avoided as far as possible. I have this piece of code which I am trying to convert to PyTorch. Is there a smart way to code it such that we do not have the for loop in it?

```
def nms(dets, scores, thresh):
    '''
    dets is a numpy array : num_dets, 6
    scores ia  nump array : num_dets,
    '''
    x1 = dets[:, 0]
    y1 = dets[:, 1]
    z1 = dets[:, 2]
    x2 = dets[:, 3]
    y2 = dets[:, 4]
    z2 = dets[:, 5]

    volume = (x2 - x1 + 1) * (y2 - y1 + 1) * (z2 - z1 + 1)
    order = scores.argsort()[::-1]  # get boxes with more ious first

    keep = []
    while order.size > 0:
        i = order[0]  # pick maxmum iou box
        keep.append(i)
        xx1 = np.maximum(x1[i], x1[order[1:]])
        yy1 = np.maximum(y1[i], y1[order[1:]])
        zz1 = np.maximum(z1[i], z1[order[1:]])
        xx2 = np.minimum(x2[i], x2[order[1:]])
        yy2 = np.minimum(y2[i], y2[order[1:]])
        zz2 = np.minimum(z2[i], z2[order[1:]])

        w = np.maximum(0.0, xx2 - xx1 + 1)  # maximum width
        h = np.maximum(0.0, yy2 - yy1 + 1)  # maxiumum height
        l = np.maximum(0.0, zz2 - zz1 + 1)  # maxiumum length
        inter = w * h * l
        ovr = inter / (volume[i] + volume[order[1:]] - inter)

        inds = np.where(ovr <= thresh)[0]
        order = order[inds + 1]

    return keep
```

I would really appreciate some help to see if we can use indexing to somehow to replace the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is just sequential, because every next iteration depends on the previous. So, you can't benefit from vector parallelization here.

Comment: So is it possible to use some other way in which I have a pytorch based nms function?

Comment: Sure. Just replace numpy functions (`np.argsort, np.maximum, np.minimum, np.where`) with torch analogs (`torch.argsort`, ...). See torch.Tensor ops [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)

Comment: But then I still have the for loop present and then it is still slow right?

Comment: Yes, you'll still have while loop. Try to perform code profiling, and remember you don't need to optimize complex code until you make sure it is a bottleneck.

Also, I don't quite understand what your code does. This algorithm can't be adapted for vector parallelization without understanding.